# How to get the exact edition of a JetBrains IDE from a plugin?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

I'm developing a plugin for all JetBrains IDEs. 
The plugin needs to know which exact flavor of JetBrains IDE it's running, some sort of string like "IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate", or "PyCharm Educational".

`ApplicationInfo` has some vague references to the IDE edition like `/idea_community_about.png` as the `aboutImageUrl` property but there doesn't appear to be anything concrete. Is there a standard way to get this data?

Comment: Maybe `ApplicationNamesInfo.getInstance().fullProductNameWithEdition`?

Comment: that looks like it will do it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get this information about the IDE, use

```
ApplicationNamesInfo.getInstance().fullProductNameWithEdition
```

From the doc string in the [source](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/core-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/application/ApplicationNamesInfo.java#L107):

> Returns full product name with edition. Vendor prefix is not included.
>
> Use only when omitting an edition may potentially cause a confusion.
>   Example #1: include the edition in generated shortcuts, since a user may have several editions installed.
>   Example #2: exclude the edition from "Restart ...?" confirmation, as it only hampers readability.
>
> **Rarely needed, consider using `getFullProductName()` instead.**

As mentioned here: if you only need to know whether you are dealing with IntelliJ or PyCharm (Community or Professional does not matter) it is often enough to use `fullProductName` instead.